# rails mongoid clear criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Mongoid::Paranoia adds a default scope to the model which generates the criteria

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:deleted_at=>{"$exists"=>false}},
  options:  {},
  class:    Line,
  embedded: false>
```

I can find deleted documents with Model.deleted which generates,

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:deleted_at=>{"$exists"=>true}},
  options:  {},
  class:    Line,
  embedded: false>
```

How can i override this so i can search both deleted and non-deleted documents.

PS `Model.unscoped` does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this(its kind of hack):

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  def self.ignore_paranoia
    all.tap {|criteria| criteria.selector.delete(:deleted_at)}
  end
end

# ignore paranoia is defined on model, so can't chain it to criteria or scopes
# but it returns criteria, so can chain other scope and criteria to it
User.ignore_paranoia.some_scope.where(:whatever => "my_custom_value")
```

Answer (score 2):

I've taken to using:

```
 def self.all!
   Mongoid::Criteria.new self
 end
```

but self.unscoped seems to work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def self.all_objects
  where(:deleted_at.in => [false, true])
end

Model.all_objects
```

**UPD**

> the deleted_at field is a datetime field, like the default created_at fields inserted by mongoid timestamps, so it throws a exception when checked for deleted_at in [true, false] which are boolean

```
def self.all_objects
  where(:deleted_at=>{"$exists"=>false}).and(:deleted_at=>{"$exists"=>true})
end
```

Comment: the deleted_at field is a datetime field, like the default created_at fields inserted by mongoid timestamps, so it throws a exception when checked for deleted_at in [true, false] which are boolean.

Comment: @fl00r It is not going to get the job done, the later criteria will override the previous criteria. It is like setting `hash[:deleted_at] = {"$exists"=>false}; hash[:deleted_at] = {"$exists"=>true}`

Answer (score 0):

If someone is searching for a way to remove one of scopes from criteria you can do it like this:

```
query = Item.published.before(DateTime.now).unblocked
query.remove_scoping(Item.before(DateTime.now))
```

You can chain criteria to query after that so it is really usefull.