# mongoid include soft deleted document

Tags: mongoid, document, soft-delete

Mongoid supports soft deletion with

```
include Mongoid::Paranoia
```

Lets suppose i have soft deleted a document from one of the collection.

Now I need a query that includes a soft deleted document from that collection.

How can I do that?

Do I need to make a separate method for this to achieve?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can find all deleted documents by query

```
 Model.deleted
```

and if you want to find deleted documents with specific condition then

```
 Model.deleted.where(:field => value)
```

Comment: No you didn't get my question. Your query just does query on deleted documents in a collection. What I need is a query that includes both deleted and not deleted documents with a condition.

Comment: you have to run the condition on deleted documents like i mentioned and on non deleted then join them to get the result.

Comment: No I dont want to query twice for my condition. Is there any way out for my condition so that i can get both deleted and not deleted documents in one query. thanks

Comment: srry for the answer actually i found a better solution i think u can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357947/rails-mongoid-clear-criteria

Comment: as per https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1064, you should not need any hacks for this now. using `Model.unscoped` should work just fine.